# Yehi Ratzon for a Choleh -- singular or plural

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, grammar-dikduk

In the Amida, the bracha of Refa'einu, there is an additional supplication one may [add](https://torah.org/learning/tefilah-eighthblessing/) and name a sick person. The text is the same as what is on [this](http://article.kiruv.com/graphics/campaigns/PI_refua_card-Final.pdf) card.

In my siddurim, I have seen the request in the singular (elokai) but in Kinot For the Ninth of Av by Rabbi Abraham Rosenfeld, the text is in the plural.

Is this a function of Tish'a B'Av? Is there a practical difference (the b'racha is in the plural, but the request is by an individual)?

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92817/1362) answer cites a text in the plural, but not necessarily one to insert in the Amida.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%90

Comment: I note that the yehi ratzon in the silent meditation after the Amida, the Y"R is in the plural which makes sense (the rebuilding of the temple benefits us all) but the Y"R before I put on my tefillin is ALSO in the plural even though it is a personal wish that laying tefillin will be as if I, as a single individual, fulfilled all sorts of other mitzvot.