# Personal Prayer in שמונה עשרה

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

The last part of the שמונה עשרה (at the end of *אלקי נצור*) allows for words of personal prayers.

Also, there's a passage in some סידורים where one davens for פרנסה within the שמע קולינו.

A) Which other parts of the שמונה עשרה is one allowed to add additional prayers such as a "יהי רצון, etc.?" Many siddurim offer a suggested text for such insertions.

B) Also, if there are a list of examples or suggestions of Tefilot that can be inserted into these parts of Shemonei Esrei... like a Yehi Ratzon or a Ribono Shel Olam or something of that sort?

Like for example in the picture below:
[image: Yehi Ratzon post אלקי נצור]

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92810/when-asking-for-personal-requests-in-shemoneh-esrei-how-should-one-phrase-them

Answer (score 2):

[THIS ARTICLE](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1242508/jewish/Can-I-Add-My-Own-Prayers-to-the-Amidah.htm) Says:

> You can insert a short personal prayer within each of the middle 13
>   blessings of the Amidah. Such a prayer should fit the theme of that
>   specific blessing. For example, ask for the speedy recovery of
>   specific person within the blessing of Refa-enu (Heal us), or pray for
>   livelihood in the blessing of Barech Aleinu (G‑d grant blessing).

[THIS ARTICLE](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/03-12-10/) Says:

> The Men of the Great Assembly, in their wisdom and divine inspiration,
>   incorporated all the ideal aspirations of the Jewish people in their
>   formulation of the Amida. They meticulously chose every word until
>   arriving at the perfect wording, with which the Jewish soul can pour
>   itself out before the Creator in the most exalted manner possible
>   (above, 1:6).
>
> Even so, if one wishes to add personal requests in the middle
>   berakhot, she may. However, in the first three berakhot, which are
>   intended to praise God, and in the last three, which are intended for
>   thanksgiving, one may not add personal requests, so as not to detract
>   from their general purpose (SA 112:1; 119:1).
>
> The personal requests permitted in the middle berakhot must be related
>   to the theme of the berakha. For example, one may pray for the sick in
>   Refa’enu, for livelihood in Birkat Ha-shanim, or for relatives to make
>   aliya in the Kibbutz Galuyot. In this respect, Shomei’a Tefila is
>   unique in that one may make all types of requests in it. Since it is
>   the culmination of the petitionary berakhot, it encompasses them all.
>   When one adds personal requests, she begins by reciting the fixed
>   formulation and adds her request just before the last line of the
>   berakha.
>
> Personal requests are not only permissible but even encouraged,
>   according to many, since the personal prayers come from the depths of
>   the heart and inspire kavana. Nevertheless, it is preferable that one
>   not prolong her personal prayers excessively, not even in Shome’a
>   Tefila, because the Amida is primarily focused on collective needs,
>   and when one adds numerous personal requests, it negates the universal
>   character of the Amida. It is better that one who wishes to add more
>   personal prayers does so after finishing all the berakhot and saying
>   (the first instance of) “Yihyu le-ratzon…” since everything recited
>   after that is not fully part of the Amida. Nevertheless, since she has
>   not yet taken three steps backwards, she is still standing before the
>   Almighty in prayer, and her personal requests are joined together with
>   the main part of the Amida (SA 119:2; MB 119:12).
>
> One must express her requests in the Amida properly. Therefore, when
>   praying for the sick, the patient’s name should be mentioned.
>   Le-khatĥila, it is good to mention the patient’s name along with his
>   mother or father’s name. However, in the presence of the patient, it
>   is unnecessary to mention his name, for her intention is clear (MB
>   119:2).

Comment: 2nd paragraph - "she" may - no "he's" allowed? Or is that on purpose, referencing Hannah's and other women's personal prayers in Tanach?

Comment: @Gary The article was written as an answer to a question asked by a female.

Comment: Ahh, yes, found the rest of the "she"s...